# Get Coordinates @Mouseenter Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to play an animation on mouseenter event in vue. But to do that I need to get the `sections` coordinates.

```
<script setup>
function getCoords(e) {
  const coords = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY } // This doesn't work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

  console.log(coords) // Error
  // ...
}
</script>

<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <section
    @mouseenter="getCoords()" />
</template>
```

I've tried, `clientX`, `pageX`, `screenX`, but they don't work. So **how** do I get the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  remove the `()` from the handler:

```html
<script setup>
function getCoords(e) {
  const coords = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY } 

  console.log(coords) 
  // ...
}
</script>

<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <section
    @mouseenter="getCoords" />
</template>
```

Comment: thank you soo much! that works! If you don't mind can you show me how could i get the coordinates of a child component? I know it's not in the question but I thought this would solve it, say that I have an img as a child of the section tag

Comment: btw, I can't upvote since this is a new account, sorry bout that

Comment: You're welcome, You can do something like `e.target.querySelector('img')`